# If the Python runtime ignores type hints, why do I get a TypeError?

Tags: python, types, typing

I already know that:

> The **Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type
> annotations**. They can be used by third party tools such as type
> checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

but why does this code check the types for me?

```
def odd(n: int) -> bool:
    return n % 2 != 0


def main():
    print(odd("Hello, world!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
C:\laragon\www\python>python type-hints.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\laragon\www\python\type-hints.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\laragon\www\python\type-hints.py", line 6, in main
    print(odd("Hello, world!"))
  File "C:\laragon\www\python\type-hints.py", line 2, in odd
    return n % 2 != 0
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

**What exactly do you mean by type hints being ignored by Python?**

Comment: It doesn't. It's just that the `%` operator does something completely different for strings than for ints.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying @Klaus D. could you give me a simple example when it does ignore them. I am new to python

Comment: The Python runtime does not enforce type *hints*. However, the type of variables is still important, and if you try to perform an operation on a different type than the one(s) intended, you may get `TypeError`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message isn't coming from checking your type hints, it's coming from the code for the `%` operator. When the left argument is a string, it performs formatting, and it reports an error when the parameters don't match the format string.

To see that type hints are ignored, write a simpler function:

```
def testfun(n: int) -> int:
    return n

print(testfun("abc"))
```

This will simply print `abc` even though it's not an `int`.

Comment: And on the other hand, if you remove the type hints from OP's code, it'll still error.

Comment: can we then say that type hints are Syntactic sugar ONLY (they make sense only when third party packages are used)?

Comment: That's not what syntactic sugar means. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Type hints are extra syntax that makes the program more self-documenting, and can also be analyzed by third-party tools. They're ignored by Python when executing the code, except that they have to be valid

Comment: Great @Barmar, now I get it, that syntactic sugar thing I saw here in SO (that's what they called type hints), that's why it threw me off. Done, marked as best answer